# Span element by class not found in XPATH

Tags: html, xpath

Hello I'm trying to access to an span element by class ID:

```
<span jsslot class="CwaK0">
 <span class="RveJvd snByac">Acepto</span>
</span>
```

using this code:

```
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@classt="RveJvd snByac"]').click()
```

But I get this error:
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@classt="RveJvd snByac"]"}

Comment: You have a typo in your XPath: You wrote `@classt` instead of `@class`.

Comment: True, but still not working with "@class"....same error. Could it be that there are two classes instead of one and so, maybe, I need to use an '_' as separator or something like that?

Comment: Does `//span[normalize-space()='Acepto']` find your targeted element?

Comment: If Span were no clickable the error normally saids "element is not clickable".... Trying normalice-space() returns the same error. It is quite rare since the element is just there....

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the problem was that the span was within an iFrame and so firstly I need to change selenium driver to point to the iframe.

```
iFrame = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//iframe[contains(@class,"widget-consent-frame")]')
        self.driver.switch_to.frame(iFrame)
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[normalize-space()="Acepto"]').click()
```